# what are solutions to ensure the security of server-side and mobile client communication?

Tags: android, iphone, security, encryption, encryption-asymmetric

My demands are as follows:

1. limit requests only from mobile device(iphone or android), that is to say, requests from programme or browser are forbidden.
2. session based conversation.
3. server-side can regonize the post data is not modified by other proxy or other ways.
4. Should consider situation that mobile device may be hacked.

Some of my thoughts to my demands:

- corresponding to 1: I want to use RSA, I generate a key and secret, client use the key to encrypt data, server use the its secret to decrypt, and check the key. But how about the key is known to others when the mobile is hacked.
- corresponding to 3: I want to use hmac algorithm and secret key to generate signature for every request.

Is there any security problems about my solutions? what are yours?

**Updated** : I am sorry that I forget to mention all the demands are talked about based on user login.

Answer (score 3):

1. You generally can't. You need to have your mobile apps authenticate to the server in some way (private account, Google account, SSL client certificate, etc.)
2. Use regular, cookie-based sessions. Use a solution that provides truly random session IDs and secure with SSL to guard against session hijacking, etc.
3. Use SSL (HTTPS)
4. Not sure what that means. If you are doing device-specific authentication, you need a way to revoke accounts, so that a stolen, etc. phone cannot be used.

Last but not least: **Do Not Try to Invent a Secure Protocol.** Use HTTPS and don't think you can create a secure solution, just because you read a book/blog/article/textbook about it.

Again: **Please Use HTTPS**.

Comment: sometimes, not all the mobile device support https.

Comment: Android and iPhone surely do. Pretty much anything else built in recent years does to. If it really doesn't, bundle OpenSSL or similar in your app. There is no excuse for not using HTTPS :)

Answer (score 0):

1) I'm not sure using RSA will fix that, unless all your mobile apps have the same public/private key combos. A browser could just as easily use RSA and encrypt the data.

A way to do this might be to check the HTTP headers coming in for headers inserted by the mobile operator and if those headers can be faked.

It's a hard problem. I'll keep thinking about it and let you know if something comes to mind.

2) For session-based encryption, you can use the [Diffie-Hellman](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange) key-exchange algorithm to negotiate a session key and then use that to lock requests to a session.

3) sounds good.

4) I think the only way around a phone being hacked is to require users to login, because you need to authenticate the user, not only the device. The other thing is that people share phones, so it may not even have been hacked. It may just have been leant out.

Comment: First thanks to your answer! To your points of view 4), it actually requires user login. It is my fault that forget to mention, and I have add updates to my question already. And to 1), I am not quite catch what you mean about the RSA.

Comment: RSA is useful for authenticating a device/computer/application and sending secret messages between a server and a client. 

If you are trying to authenticate that a request was made by your app by encrypting a message and sending it to the server, what stops anyone else copying the encrypted message and sending that? They wouldn't even need to hack the phone. They'd just need to use a packet sniffer and steal the encrypted message. Or am I misunderstanding you?

Answer (score 0):

Consider using ASIHTTPRequest api, and use SSL for more protection. For hacked mobile , user login is a convenient way to achieve it and everytime user send POST request you can ask for the pass.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. But in fact, I am to deside server-side issue, so ASIHTTPRequest api is the client job. I have token consideration of SSL solution, but not all mobile or ISP support SSL, so it is not a general solution.

Comment: Then you should try asking this question on serverfault.com , may you will get some logical answer